# vbでDatetimeの差分の求め方

Tags: vb.net

vbを使っています。
a="2020/02/07"とb="2020/02/06"の引き算をして"1日"という結果を得たいです。

まず、Date.parse(a.Tostring)を使ってDatetime型に変換しました。
次に、Date.parse(a.Tostring)-Date.parse(b.Tostring)でtimespan型を得ました。
これをexcelに出力すると"737461"という値が表示されました。

１つ目の質問ですが、この"737461"が何なのか分かりませんでした。秒かなとも思ったのですが、１日を秒に変換すると86400秒なので違うようです。
教えていただければ幸いです。
２つ目の質問は、この数字をどのように変換すれば"1日"になるのでしょうか？
ご指導よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: どのように「excelに出力」したのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問内容をVisualStudio2019のVisualBasicコンソールプログラムにすると以下(最初のDim 3行)のようになるでしょう。
Excelに出力では無く単に文字列化して表示すると：

```
Sub Main()
    Dim a = "2020/02/07"
    Dim b = "2020/02/06"
    Dim ts = Date.Parse(a.ToString()) - Date.Parse(b.ToString())

    Console.WriteLine("TimeSpan = " + ts.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("TimeSpan Days = " + ts.Days.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("TimeSpan Hours = " + ts.Hours.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("TimeSpan Minutes = " + ts.Minutes.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("TimeSpan Seconds = " + ts.Seconds.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("TimeSpan MilliSeconds = " + ts.Milliseconds.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("TimeSpan TotalDays = " + ts.TotalDays.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("TimeSpan TotalHours = " + ts.TotalHours.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("TimeSpan TotalMinutes = " + ts.TotalMinutes.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("TimeSpan TotalSeconds = " + ts.TotalSeconds.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("TimeSpan TotalMilliSeconds = " + ts.TotalMilliseconds.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("TimeSpan Ticks = " + ts.Ticks.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("")

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

結果は以下になります。

```
TimeSpan = 1.00:00:00

TimeSpan Days = 1
TimeSpan Hours = 0
TimeSpan Minutes = 0
TimeSpan Seconds = 0
TimeSpan MilliSeconds = 0

TimeSpan TotalDays = 1
TimeSpan TotalHours = 24
TimeSpan TotalMinutes = 1440
TimeSpan TotalSeconds = 86400
TimeSpan TotalMilliSeconds = 86400000
TimeSpan Ticks = 864000000000
```

"737461"という数字は何処にも出てこないので、「これをexcelに出力すると"737461"という値が表示されました。」という **excelに出力する** 処理に何か問題があるのではないでしょうか？

**日単位の差分** は、元のデータが日単位ならば **Days** / **TotalDays** のどちらでも、時分とか含まれる可能性がある場合、時分を切り捨てなら **Days** 、時分の端数込みなら **TotalDays** のプロパティ値を(必要なら文字列化して)利用すれば良いでしょう。

Comment: kunif様　いつもご指導ありがとうございます。遅くなって申し訳ありません。私のミスでした。aの値のスコープが悪く、aの値がクリアされており、おかしい計算結果になっておりました。ご迷惑をお掛けいたしました。